# Express React.js MySql data into variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, express

#### Hii! I was coding my web app when I ran into some trouble.

**I want to make it so this class will run only if "swishes" ,which is a value from a table in my MySQL db, is above 0.**

```
     var thepos = 1;
    export default class WishStick extends React.Component {
      render() {      
    var vars = standardwishitems(stars);
    const WishShow = WishResults(stars, vars[0]);
    const anim = pullanim(stars);
    giveItem(vars[1], thepos);
    thepos +=1;
    return(
        <div>
            <Animation />
            {WishShow}
        </div>

    );
}
 }
```

**This is my server code :**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const {
createPool
} = require('mysql');
const { response } = require('express');

const db = createPool({
host:"My ip address :P",
user:"my username :P",
password:"my password :P",
database:"player"
})

const account = createPool({
host:"My ip address :P",
user:"my username :P",
password:"my password :P",
database:"account"
})

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));

app.get('/api/get', (req, res)=>{

const wishes = "SELECT swishes, pwishes FROM account WHERE id = 11";
account.query(wishes, (err, result) => {
    res.send(result);
    
});
});

app.post("/api/insert", (req, res)=>{

const pos = req.body.pos
const vnum = req.body.vnum
const additem = "INSERT INTO player.item (owner_id, pos, count, vnum) VALUES ('11', ?, '1', 
?)"
db.query(additem, [pos, vnum], (err, result) => {
    console.log(pos, vnum, err);
})
res.send("a mers");
});
app.listen(3001, () =>{
console.log("running on port 3001");
});
```

**This is the result from /api/get :**

```
[{"swishes":999,"pwishes":999}]
```

**I have already tried to search online, but every method I saw and tried took the query into array and mapped into h1 or li tags, which is not what I am trying to do. I am trying to get the value from "swishes" into a variable , let's say wishNum, so then for example I can do if(wishNum > 0) {
return WishStick  }else {alert('You do not have enough wishes!')} .
Do you know how I may go about doing this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it guys! This is how you do it:

```
wishes.map(val => { s_wishes = parseInt(val.swishes)})
```

Example :

```
var s_wishes;
const { error, isLoaded, wishes } = this.state;
if (error) {
return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
} else if (!isLoaded) {
return <div>Loading...</div>;
} else {
wishes.map(val => { s_wishes = parseInt(val.swishes)});
console.log(s_wishes);
}
```